# How to create different users on different hosts

Tags: ansible

List of hosts:
192.168.110.1
.......
192.198.110.10.

On each of them you need to create a user:
Bob
...
Alice

I want to implement it in one playbook so as not to run it 10 times for each host.

Users create something like this:

```
vars_prompt:
 - name: "user_name"
   prompt: "User name"    
   private: no   
 - name: "user_password"    
   prompt: "Enter a password for the user"    
   private: yes    
   encrypt: "md5_crypt"    
   confirm: yes    
   salt_size: 7
tasks:
 - name: "add new user" 
   user: 
     name: "{{user_name}}" 
     password: "{{user_password}}" 
     shell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: `create a user: Bob ... Alice`.. you mean, Bob or Alice?

Comment: At 192.168.110.1 create a Bob.
At 192.168.110.2 create Alice.
....

Answer (score 1):

You can add different host groups in your `inventory` file:

```
[alice_hosts]
192.168.110.2

[bob_hosts]
192.168.110.1
```

And then run some commands in your `playbook.yml` only on these specific groups:

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    # Do some common stuff

- hosts: alice_hosts

  tasks:

   - name: "add new user" 
     user: 
       name: alice
       password: alice_password
       shell: /bin/bash

- hosts: bob_hosts

  tasks:

   - name: "add new user" 
     user: 
       name: bob
       password: bob_password
       shell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: When creating users, I use vars_prompt, I need them to change for each user.  I enter this data into the console.

Comment: My task is to create users on each of the 100 computers.  User names and passwords are known to me.  But launching a playbook 100 times is not correct.